# PowerPoint VBA - extending chart data range

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I am trying to create a VBA macro in PowerPoint that will extend the range of an excel embedded chart to the last row with data. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

You can use "lastrow," which is expressed as an integer.

```
Table.LastRow
```

So, depending on your slide, you might say something like

```
ActivePresentation.Slides(3).Shapes(5).Table.lastRow
```

to get the last row number.